# React Card does not expand with search dropdown results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As you can see the search results contain around ten items. However, the result set is cut off at the bottom of the div of class `div-summary`

How can I modify the `div-summary` such that the search result set is shown?

[image]
[image]

```
.div-summary{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    argin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: try overflow scroll it may work

Comment: can you add code of this div and dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by changing `overflow` to `visible`

```
.div-summary{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    argin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline;
}
```